# Seemingly basic question about extending a function in a Sobolev space

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose we have a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a specific function $f \in L^{k,p}(\Omega)$. Now suppose that one can prove that for the domain $\Omega$ in question it is impossible to construct an extension operator $\Lambda: L^{k,p}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Does it follow that $f \notin L^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ?

By an extension operator I mean an operator that maps $f$ to itself as in: $\Lambda f|_\Omega = f$. Basically the question is, is it possible to have a function $f \in L^{k,p}(\Omega)$ AND $f \in L^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ while simultaneously being able to prove that it is impossible to construct the mapping $\Lambda: L^{k,p}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ? Or is the fact that $\Lambda$ does not exist enough to show that $f \notin L^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ?

Comment: On its face, it doesn't make sense to say $f \in L^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ because by definition it is only defined on $\Omega$.  One would have to ask whether there *exists* any extension of $f$ in $L^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (in general it is not unique).  But this is certainly possible; for instance, if $f$ happens to be compactly supported inside $\Omega$, then we can simply extend it by setting it to be zero outside $\Omega$.

Comment: @NateEldredge So what you are saying is that one does not define a function independently of its domain: if $f$ is defined on $\Omega$, then there is no such thing as $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is only the extension of $f$ from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
This brings me to another question then: let's say an inequality involving $f$ is true on $\Omega$. Would the lack of an extension operator directly mean that this inequality does not hold on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? Or that in some sense, it doesn't even make sense to pose the inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?